# How to upgrade com.squareup.okhttp(4.6.0) in GRPC OkHttp version (1.29.0)?

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, grpc, okhttp, grpc-java

gRPC-Java with lastest Version of GRPC OkHttp » 1.29.0
dependency - "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.29.0"
link - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-okhttp/1.29.0

which is use okhttp(com.squareup.okhttp:2.7.4) but I want to upgrade into in higher(4.6.0).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwTFn.png)

[screenshot from - https://mvnrepository.com]

Because in older version have some security issues in SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security issues in OkHttp 2.7.4 are in parts of the code not used by gRPC. In particular, none of the TLS code from OkHttp is used. There are no security issues in your configuration unless you also use OkHttp 2.7.4’s APIs directly.

Later releases of OkHttp use a different package name: `okhttp3` instead of `com.squareup.okhttp`, so upgrading OkHttp won't help you anyway.

Comment: Where can we see the latest compatible release versions for `grpc-okhttp`?  I am getting an error: **Could not resolve io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.36.4**